# making UI rerender while adding state to comments on a post

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Post comment, in my react application, which has a component Comments attachted to it.

As of now, the comments are mapped and displayed in the comments component

```
return (
  <ul className="comments">
    {this.props.comments.map(comment =>
      <li className="comment" key={comment.id}>
        <div className="comment-header">
          <p className="comment-author-name">{comment.author.name}</p>
          <Button 
        className="btn delete-btn"
        disabled={this.state.loading}
         onClick={() => this.deleteCommentHandler(comment.id)}>
         {this.state.loading ? 'Deleting comment': 'Delete'}
        </Button>
        <Button 
        className="btn edit-btn"
        disabled={this.state.loading}
         onClick={() => this.deleteCommentHandler(comment.id)}>
         {this.state.loading ? 'Editing comment': 'Edit'}
        </Button>
        </div>
        <p className="comment-content">{comment.contents}</p>

      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
```

As of now i have an issue, with the fact that, the state is universal, which means that if more comments are posted by a user, all the comments will render the conditional check in the

```
{this.state.loading ? 'Deleting comment': 'Delete'}
```

part. Furthermore i want the UI to update, whenever the deleteCommentHandler is clicked

```
deleteCommentHandler = (id) =>{
  console.log(id);
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  })
  this.commentMapper.deletePostComments(id).then(res =>{ // calls another function which makes a serverside request and deletes the comment from the backend
    this.setState({loading: false})
    console.log('hwhwhwh');
  });
}
```

should i make a Comment component and render that with the state loading, and a method to update the UI if a comment is deleted, or can i simply make more handlers to handle they state for each comment, and make the UI re render that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why universalizing the loading state, All you need is to keep each element with it's own loading state by making the Comment a React Component and managing it's own state internally will keep your flow more controlled.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "YOURBUTTONPATH";

export default class Comment extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
    this.deleteCommentHandler = this.deleteCommentHandler.bind(this);
  }
  deleteCommentHandler(id) {
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    // If this function is generic and related the parent component pass it as a props to Comment Component.
    this.commentMapper.deletePostComments(id).then(res => {
      // calls another function which makes a serverside request and deletes the comment from the backend
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      console.log("hwhwhwh");
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { comment } = this.props;
    return (
      <li className="comment" key={comment.id}>
        <div className="comment-header">
          <p className="comment-author-name">{comment.author.name}</p>
          <Button
            className="btn delete-btn"
            disabled={this.state.loading}
            onClick={() => this.deleteCommentHandler(comment.id)}
          >
            {this.state.loading ? "Deleting comment" : "Delete"}
          </Button>
          <Button
            className="btn edit-btn"
            disabled={this.state.loading}
            onClick={() => this.deleteCommentHandler(comment.id)}
          >
            {this.state.loading ? <Loading text={"Editing comment"} {...this.state}/> : "Edit"}
          </Button>
        </div>
        <p className="comment-content">{comment.contents}</p>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

and your mapped comments will be like this:

```
return (
  <ul className="comments">
    {this.props.comments.map(comment =>
      <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

Loading component:

```
export const Loading = ({ loading, text }) => (loading ? <p>{text}</p> : null);
```

Comment: Super cool thanks, another isuue i had, as i addressed, is that whenver a component as deleted, the UI is not updated, untill the page reloads, or a new comment is posted, will this fix that?

Comment: In the comment component call a delete function from the parent Component which will delete the id of your comment from the array of objects source of your "this.props.comment" whether it's a redux store or a state.

Comment: That will instantly update your UI without refreshing the page ;) .

Comment: I had a discussion with a friend, who said that i instead should make a component called loading which would handle the loading state. But i thinlk that would not be good practise, since you are outsourcing a "state" to a seperate component

Comment: Even though the Loading component will just act as a loading component controlled by a Boolean (true or false) props that will enable and disable it's UI rendering. Making the loading a component is worth it just in case you need universal and generic component to have a loader SVG or whatever UI you need to render while loading.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I belive Comment might be a reserved keyword in React, i might just name it SIngleComment

Comment: It's not a reserved keyword. You can chose whatever name pleases you but make sure it's not a reserved keyword :P .

Comment: Super Thank you, i just implemented The code, and everything works fine with The loading state, but The UI does still not Update, whenever The delete button is clicked.

Comment: As I told you in the comments above, To implement a delete from the UI define a function which deletes the comment from the source `array` of comments which will re-render your react component with the spliced new array.

Comment: Take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

and:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

To findByIndex and splice.

Comment: Okay perfect, so i can just use those methods, where i take the comment or id in as the parameter?

Comment: How can i find the index by the key?